# react-select - onInputChange event doesn't records the selected option's value, then how to get it?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select

According to [the async](https://react-select.com/home#async) example on the component's doc, the `onInputChange` event only records the value you type, but once you select an option, everything is cleared.

I think the aim should instead be to get the selected value...

I have tried to find another event that will return the selected value, but I still don't get it. Curiously none of the examples touches that aspect ...

Please how can I retrieve the selected option ? Note that I am using `v2`

Comment: Can you please share a code snippet of what you're trying to do?

Comment: I just edited my question.

Comment: I would have delete this question if possible. I just had to use onChange instead of onInputChange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@acmoune answered his own question in the comments, but I'm putting it in as an 'Answer', for those who find this question on SO later.

The React-Select `onChange` event is fired when an option is selected. You can use this to get the 'selected' value. This is outlined in the [StateManager Props](https://react-select.com/props#statemanager-props) section of the React-Select documentation.